# Cannot update or save data on second or next user in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, express, backend

May I know what is the problem with my code for the backend. I try to create a place and update it in the user database. The problem is If I only have 1 user. The database can create and update the data but if I have more than 2 then, the data cannot be updated or created. Here is my code. I have been working on this part for so long, that I cannot find the solution.

```
const createFile = async (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return next(
      new HttpError('Invalid inputs passed, please check your data.', 422)
    );
  }

  const { userId, Dataset } = req.body;

  const createdFile = new File({
    userId,
    Dataset,
  });
  let user;
  try {
    user = await User.findById(userId);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Creating place failed, please try again 1',
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  if (!user) {
    const error = new HttpError('Could not find user for provided id', 404);
    return next(error);
  }

  try {
    const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
    sess.startTransaction();
    await createdFile.save({ session: sess });
    user.Dataset.push(createdFile);
    await user.save({ session: sess });
    await sess.commitTransaction();
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Creating place failed, please try again.2',
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  res.status(201).json({ files: createdFile });
};
```

The error message that I got

```
Error: User validation failed: _id: Error, expected `_id` to be unique. Value: `62c661c629d1cb99768efd05`
    at ValidationError.inspect (C:\Users\acit\Desktop\FYP Code\FYP Code\backend2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:48:26)
    at internal/per_context/primordials.js:23:32
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:783:19)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:337:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (internal/util/inspect.js:2016:40)
    at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1898:10)
    at console.value (internal/console/constructor.js:323:14)
    at console.log (internal/console/constructor.js:358:61)
    at createFile (C:\Users\acit\Desktop\FYP Code\FYP Code\backend2\controllers\files-controller.js:102:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  errors: {
    _id: ValidatorError: Error, expected `_id` to be unique. Value: `62c661c629d1cb99768efd05`
        at validate (C:\Users\acit\Desktop\FYP Code\FYP Code\backend2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1321:13)
        at C:\Users\acit\Desktop\FYP Code\FYP Code\backend2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1297:24
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'unique',
      path: '_id',
      value: new ObjectId("62c661c629d1cb99768efd05"),
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'User validation failed'
}
```

Comment: log the ```err``` object and post it

Comment: "message": "Creating place failed, please try again.2"

Comment: not the error message in the response. The ```err``` object you are getting in the ```catch``` block.

Comment: that is the err message

Answer (score 0):

It already settle, I reroll the mongoose-unique-validator to 2.0.3 version

I use this command

```
npm install mongoose-unique-validator@2.0.3 --legacy-peer-deps
```

hope that someone with same issues as mine find my post and can help them to solve the same issues